# Parsing date from Calendar in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date, calendar

I am having following function

```
public static Date parseDate(String date, String format) throws ParseException
 {
         SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
         return formatter.parse(date);
 }
```

I am using this as follows in my code

```
Calendar eDate = Calendar.getInstance();
eDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,10);
Date date = null;
  try {
   date = parseDate(eDate.getTime().toString(),"yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But it is throwing -

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: The date is probably unparseable. Initializing (not constructing) eDate might help.

Comment: Read @Carl Smotricz's answer....but as for your format `"yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` you're reading minutes (mm) instead of month (MM)...just a thought!

Comment: Oops :P Yeah but I tried changing that to MM, but same error is coming

Comment: I fixed the format string in the original post to reduce confusion among readers.

Comment: Got it running guys. Thanks a ton :) Used BaluC 's solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The format is not stored in the `Date`. It is stored in the `String`. The `Date#toString()` returns a **fixed** format which is described in its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()).

Do the formatting only *at the moment* you need to display a `Date` to a human as a `String`.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 10);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Note that `MM` stands for months and `mm` for minutes. See also [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: I did'n know that the an object of Calendar was automatically converted into an Date with getTime() +1

Answer (score 5):

You'll be happy to hear that there's never a need to parse a date from a `Calendar` object: The way to pull a `Date` out of a `Calendar` is via the `getTime()` method.

---

EDIT:

To output the date in `eDate` in ISO style format:

```
final DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
String formattedDate = isoFormat.format(eDate.getTime());
```

That's untested, but I think it should work.

Comment: You could use `Date date = calendar.getTime();` and then format it via `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss").format(date);`

Comment: Then it's time to address the next step. You have a Date, you want a String, at that point you want to use `SimpleDateFormat.format()` on it. I'll put that into my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You're currently *formatting* with the default format from `java.util.Date`, and then *parsing* with a potentially different format. You should also change your format string - it's currently using a 12 hour clock with no am/pm indicator, and minutes twice. I think you mean: "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss"

Comment: This is the date it is unable to parse "Jul 21, 2010 7:24:07 PM"

Comment: @Vishal: Yes, that's because you're formatting it with java.util.Date.toString.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting a Zulu Timestamp (UNIX), `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`. Then you define the format as `yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss` and try to parse the timestamp with this pattern. Which doesn't match.

You could use `Date date = calendar.getTime();` and then format it via `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss").format(date);`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `toString()` for anything like that. `toString()` should be used only for debug messages.

Use `DateFormat.format(..)` to produce a string in a predictable form.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the date returned by the calendar, instead of transforming it into string and back into a date (apparently using a wrong date format). The date can be obtained by:

```
eDate.getTime()
```

There seems to be no need for SimpleDateFormat in your case.

Comment: The `Calendar#getTime()` returns `java.util.Date`, not `long`.

Comment: I was assuming that the sample code was a test case, not actual production code.  Had he got the format right, it's actually a pretty good test.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Date.toString() method.

The api states that it returns it in
the format:

```
dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

which is:

```
Mon Jan 28 14:22:07 EST 2004
```

You are telling the parser to expect: `2004-01-28 14-22-07`

Answer (score 0):

```
eDate.getTime().toString()
```

returns a String representation of a date in this format:

dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy  (see the java.util.Date API).

You are trying to parse a date using this format:

yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss .

The code is correctly throwing the ParseException.